# What is the difference between row.append and $$.filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling for the last day or so trying to get onclick to work for my program.  After exhaustive research I've determined onclick is working by design, but the program I'm using seems to be hampering onclick.

For starters this section works fine as written in the program...but hampers onclick from working...

```
        insertDeleteLink = function(row) {
            var delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.'),
                addCssSelector = $.trim(options.addCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');

            var delButtonHTML = '<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a>';
            if (options.deleteContainerClass) {
            } else {
                row.append(delButtonHTML);
            }
```

However, if I replace row.append ( the last line ) with filter related commands as shown below....

```
        insertDeleteLink = function(row) {
            var delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.'),
                addCssSelector = $.trim(options.addCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');

            var delButtonHTML = '<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a>';
            if (options.deleteContainerClass) {
            } else {
                $$.filter(':last').after(delButtonHTML);
                delButtonHTML = $$.filter(':last').next();
            }
```

I've tried something like this...and it works for my elements that have not been appended.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".add-row").on('click', function() {
      console.log("Here I am.");  
    });
  });
```

It works fine.  But when I switch this to my appended element it doesn't work.  No log messages....But when I don't use append and I use the filter commands instead...they work just fine for my element.  The problem is the filter commands break the rest of the program.

Any thoughts on what is changing when I am changing the append statement to the filter statements is appreciated.  I'm a Javascript newb and have been at this one for a couple days now.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you somehow replicate this in working code  or is this live somewhere ?

Comment: @Swati Thank you for your help.  I have switched creating the link as a string to an element per someone else's suggestion and it still doesn't help.  I can easily replicate it...it shows up in DOM but will only delete the first one.    Bizarre because same program has another button that works just fine.

Comment: @Swati I think the problem may lie with not having adding listeners for this activity?  I've researched this thoroughly and I think that may be my problem.  I have multiple events that have the same class name...and only the first one executes....My latest line of thought is that is what is preventing my clicks from being recognized.

Comment: @Swati I'm pretty sure I have it narrowed down.  All of my links have the same class name and no other identifiers that are unique.  I believe that's why only the first event fires.  I'm researching how to deal with that now.

Comment: It will help a lot if you can replicate this somewhere in order to see what are you doing or trying to do... I´m not sure but does the add-row class is the element that you are adding? If so, instead of injecting the event to that class add it to the parent, something like this: `$(".add-row-parentElement").on("click", ".add-row", function(){})` this will add an event listener to the parent and check when something inside the parent with class add-row is clicked. Your actual code wont work because when you added the listener the new elements are not on dom so they dont have the click listener

Comment: @Frankusky Thanks for the idea.  I'll see what I can come up with.  I do believe my problem is that I am dynamically adding links with the same name and that's the main problem.  From what I've read the listener goes away after the first one is clicked unless I add listeners as well.  I'm researching that today.